# How to exit gitlab job when script fails

Tags: bash, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have bash script that executes multiple times in single a job. If the script fails I want to exit out of the job and mark the job as failed.

**plan.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
terraform init 
terraform plan -out=${PLAN_FILE_NAME}
```

gitlab job

```
plan:
 before_script:   
     - chmod +x ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/gitlab/deploy/plan/plan.sh  
     - export PATH="$PATH:${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/gitlab/deploy/plan"   
 stage:plan
 script:
    - cd ${FOLDER1}
    - plan.sh

    - cd ${FOLDER2}
    - plan.sh

    - cd ${FOLDER2}
    - plan.sh
 artifacts:
   - "${FOLDER1}/${PLAN_FILE_NAME}"
   - "${FOLDER2}/${PLAN_FILE_NAME}"
   - "${FOLDER3}/${PLAN_FILE_NAME}"
```

currently if the command `terraform init` or `terraform plan` fails for a folder, still the script keeps executing for the next folder and finally its marking the job as successful.
I want to exit out of job and mark the job as failed when there is an error during `terraform init` or `terraform plan`.

What would be a better way to handle this?

Comment: I think gitlab pipelines get marked as failed as soon as the script stage exits with a non-zero exit code. Why not do something like `if ! terraform init; then exit 1; fi` etc etc

Comment: Basically GitLab already does what you’re asking, but your shell script isn’t exiting and returning a nonzero exit code when an error is encountered on one of the lines

Comment: So, in very brief, change `#!/bin/bash` to `#!/bin/bash -e` or add `set -e` as the next line of the script. (The latter is somewhat more robust, in that it also works if you explicitly run the script with `bash plan.sh` instead of the otherwise required `bash -e plan.sh`. But you are simply running `plan.sh` so this point is moot here.)